# Calf cramps after swimming - pain persisting 2 days later

Tags: cramps, calf

So, 2 days ago I was swimming in the ocean with my kids for a while, I also did some freestyle swimming for exercise - about 250M. I swim a decent amount but that plus just swimming with my kids was more than usual.

On exiting the water I got these horrible cramps in both of my calves. The left one was bad but the right side was extreme and persisted for 2 mins or so. When it ended my calves were sore and felt really weak. Two day later and they are a little better but still very sore and I can't really stand on my toes without my right calf giving out.

I should note, I may have been a little dehydrated and the water (atlantic ocean on the coast of Maine) was cold by mid-to-late August standards.

I can still walk on it, though - to be honest it feels more like I gave it the workout of a lifetime as opposed to a muscle strain.

What is the mechanism of this pain - is it the same as an intense workout or is it something else that just feels that way. Subjectively, It feels the same except for the weakness.

I had my wife give me a calf massage last night - she said that it felt like there was a baseball under the skin of my right calf. Boy did that massage hurt.

Comment: I would have it evaluated. Especially if you have a "baseball" lump, it's possible that you have a persistent cramp that has knotted up the muscle (Google calf heart attack), a possible muscle tear from the cramp, any number of things from very minor to serious. Get someone who knows what they are doing to take a look and diagnose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might get closed as a duplicate of [how to prevent calf cramps while swimming](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2986/how-to-prevent-calf-cramps-while-swimming?rq=1), but you directly asked this so I'll try to answer it for you:

> What is the mechanism of this pain - is it the same as an intense
>   workout or is it something else that just feels that way.

There are two competing theories (neither proven, empirically) on EAMC ([exercise associated muscle cramps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exercise-associated_muscle_cramps)).

The first idea is a loss of sodium. This causes the muscles to eventually change shape internally, causing structural modifications that take a while to heal from.

The second idea is [neuromuscular fatigue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakness#Neuromuscular_fatigue). Your neurons require [a certain amount of various chemicals in order to send and receive electrical impulses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Na%2B/K%2B-ATPase). In fact, [the limiting factor of strength tends to be intracellular calcium](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/20879/7091).

If you're feeling it two days later, especially if it seems to have gotten worse 24-48 hours after, you're most likely dealing with [Delayed Onset Muscle Soreness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/19157/7091).

In all cases, training helps (once you can walk without wincing). A large part of physical training is the actual [efficiency of signal processing that your brain uses to activate muscles](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/22436/why-is-my-speed-of-thought-reduced-on-days-after-doing-a-lot-of-sports/22437#22437). Your body will adapt to the new stress, and two large components of that adaptation are neuromuscular and more basic skeletal muscle tissue growth.

Comment: Thanks interesting stuff feeling better today - stretched a lot last night played some hoop today - felt fine.